# How to send an error message when c-string user input empty?

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

So I'm trying to make a program right now.
I try to use a c-string to get the name and output the user input using menu #2
Also, I want to send an error message and ask the user to input the name again when user input blank.

The real problem is, I know how to send the error message when I have an empty string, but not when I have an empty c- string.

This is my program.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void inputPika(char[]);
void display_menu();
void displayPika(char[]);
void display_menu()
{
    //Display menu for user selection
    cout << "The Name game: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Pika Name " << endl;
    cout << "2. Display Pika Name " << endl;
}
void inputPika(char a[])
{
    const int SIZE = 40;


    cin.getline(a, SIZE);
}
void displayPika(char a[])
{
    cout << a << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int pick = 0;
    const int SIZE = 40;
    char name[SIZE];
    cin.ignore();

    while (true)
    {
        display_menu();
        cin >> pick;
        cin.ignore();

        switch (pick)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "1. Input Name: ";

            inputPika(name);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "2. Display Name: ";
            displayPika(name);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

(Sadly, my other functions need c- string so I can't change all thing to string)
Also, another question.

When I run my program, the program didn't run automatically, which I have to press the enter to see the menu option. I'm not sure why my program did this.

Comment: To check if a C string is empty you may simply `strlen(str) == 0`. For second question you should check that `cin.ignore()` call...

Comment: Not really, I'd put it in `inputPika` but note that for C strings you may consider to use C I/O. `getline()` (for example, if available). In that case you can simply check its return value.

Comment: oh Okay thank you :D I think I fix the second problem. I'm still working on first problem, but you help me a lot. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the "automatic run" you should remove the following:

```
cin.ignore();
```

In your case, empty "name" will reflect in `'\0'` (null terminator) char in your buffer, so you can check if `name[0] == '\0'` after your return from the `inputPika()` function.